# How to set a div top of the stack order when two div zindexes are max

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have div1 and div2. both  z-index values are 2147483647(max values). i want div2 to overlaping div1. But i can't reduce div1 z-index value. also can't implement any js function for reduce or updating z-index value.

Following code for div2 which is generated by js:

```
const defultCSS = `
  box-sizing:border-box;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, 'Apple Color Emoji', 'Segoe UI Emoji', 'Segoe UI Symbol';
  font-size:16px;
  vertical-align:middle;`;

const initialCSS = `all:initial;${defultCSS}`;


function displayUi(prev: any) {
  const optionsHTML = ccPositions
    .concat(['replace'])
    .map((pos) => `<option>${pos}</option>`)
    .join('\n');
  const headerHTML = `
  <div id="pick-selector-top-bar" style="${initialCSS};position:fixed;padding:10px;top:0;right:0;color:black;z-index:${Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER};background-color:${tcolors.blue[0]}">
    <button id="pick-selector-btn" style="${initialCSS};padding: 4px 15px;margin-right:5px;background:${tcolors.blue[6]};color:white;border:0;border-radius:3px">Pick</button>
    <button id="pick-selector-parent-btn" style="${initialCSS};padding:4px 15px;margin-right:5px;background:${tcolors.blue[6]};color:white;border:0;border-radius:3px">Parent</button>
    <select id="pick-selector-select-box" style="${initialCSS};padding:4px 8px;width:150px;height:auto;border:1px solid #ccc;border-radius:3px;">
      <option disabled selected value="">select</option>
      ${optionsHTML}
    </select>
    <span id="pick-selector-displayer" style="${initialCSS};padding:4px;width:240px;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;white-space:nowrap;display:inline-block;"></span>
    <button id="pick-selector-copy-btn" style="${initialCSS};padding: 4px 15px;margin-right:5px;background:${tcolors.blue[6]};color:white;border:0;border-radius:3px">Copy</button>
    <div id="pick-selector-valid-displayer"></div>
  </div>
  `;
  document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', headerHTML);
  const copyBtn = document.getElementById('pick-selector-copy-btn');
  const parentBtn = document.getElementById('pick-selector-parent-btn');
  const selectBox = document.getElementById(
    'pick-selector-select-box'
  ) as HTMLSelectElement;
  copyBtn.addEventListener('click', copyToClipboard);
  parentBtn.addEventListener('click', parentSelector);
  selectBox.addEventListener('change', (e: any) => selectPosition(e.target.value));
  let prevValid = false;
  if (prev) {
    const selElement = document.querySelector(prev.target);
    if (selElement) {
      prevValid = true;
      displaySelectorOptions(selElement, prev.target);
      checkElementStatus(prev.target);
      selectBox.value = prev.position;
      selectPosition(prev.position);
    }
  }
  enableBtn('#pick-selector-copy-btn', prevValid);
  enableBtn('#pick-selector-parent-btn', prevValid);
  enableBtn('#pick-selector-select-box', prevValid);
}
```

id="pick-selector-top-bar" as div2. this div want to be placed top the stack.`Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER = 9007199254740991`

div1 css:

```
div1{
    background-color: rgb(0, 128, 192);
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    opacity: 0.8;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    display: block;
    z-index: 2147483647;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 16px 0px;
    font-size: 120%;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: none;
}
```

Followig div1 css code was copied from elements tap. I don't have div1 source code. this is generated by client. that's why i can't reduce div1 z-index value.

is there any other way to set div2 as top of the stack?

Comment: Post your HTML too. We need a [mcve]. Also, unless you position an element, the z-index property won't do anything.

Comment: I don't know why this overlapping problem occurred as `div1` has `display: none` property. It won't be displayed.

Comment: @j08691 i updated my post. please check again.

Comment: @Kenny i updated my post. please check again